# Count all levels with no outlines as children

Tags: excel, vba, row, parent-child, outline

I am trying to find a solution to count the number of rows which are at the last outline level. In the image as you can see this is the result I desire. I want to detect a row in the Range where the outline level only has children and no other outline level below.[image]

Could anybody offer some pointers in how to find this outline level please?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.outlinelevel

Answer (score 1):

The outline level of a range (row or column) can be checked using `OutlineLevel`. As far as I see, you want to compare the outline level with the one of the next row: If the outline level of the next row is larger, it is a child, else the row has no childs.
Check the next function:

```
Function hasChildren(r As Range) As Boolean
    hasChildren = r.EntireRow.OutlineLevel < r.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.OutlineLevel
End Function
```

Comment: Thankyou for your help! How do I call this function buddy?

Comment: Like any other function in Excel, eg put `=hasChildren(A2)` in D2

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that this will not recalculate automatically when the outline level is changed.